# AFNetworking: How to convert this header request to use AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have the following code below that uses a rather old library called ASIHTTPRequest. I am looking to upgrade the library, but need a little help to make sure I am doing it correctly and to get my feet wet. This is the code I need to convert to AFNetworking. Any tips or suggestions is appreciated.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
[request setDelegate:self];

NSMutableDictionary *userinfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[userinfo setObject:NSStringFromSelector(self.didFinishSelector) forKey:@"didFinishSelector"];
[userinfo setObject:NSStringFromSelector(self.didFailSelector) forKey:@"didFailSelector"];

[request setUserInfo:userinfo];
[request setUserAgentString:USER_AGENT];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
[request addRequestHeader:@"apiKey" value:apiKey];
[request setRequestMethod:method];
```

Comment: You need to do `POST` with `AFNetworking` right ?

Comment: Yes, I need to do POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `AFNetworking` the code should look like below

```
    NSDictionary *parameters=@{"key":value};//The values you want to POST arrange in dictionary.

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

   [manager.requestSerializer setValue:apiKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"apiKey"];
   [manager.requestSerializer setValue:USER_AGENT forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

   [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:60];



    [manager POST:urlStr parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Result %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);

    }];
```

I hope it helps. Cheers.